# Media breakpoints not applying properly, probably something really simple

Tags: html, css

my media breakpoints aren't applying as they should. I put together a simplified example to demonstrate.

In the below example, the div "myDiv" should read:

- "normal width", when no media breakpoints are applying
- "mw1200", when the screen has a max width of 1200px
- "mw992", when the screen has a max width of 992px
- "mw768", when the screen has a max width of 768px

Instead, it's reading "normal width", when over max-width of 1200px, and "mw1200", when below.

```css
.myContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.myDiv {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.myDiv:after {
  content: 'normal width';
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .myDiv:after {
    content: 'mw768';
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
  .myDiv:after {
    content: 'mw992';
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  .myDiv:after {
    content: 'mw1200';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <div class="myDiv">
    myDiv inside myContainer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to declare the breakpoints the other way round: the widest first, else it is not overwritten by the next since it is also matching the next ;)

Comment: *FACEPALM* 

Thanks!

Comment: as a sidenote, it is a good habit to declare a min-width and max-width within media queries. unless its the bottom or top end.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably refactor this and go mobile-first. You could do something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style>

.myContainer {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.myDiv {
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.myDiv:after {
    content: 'mw768';
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .myDiv:after {
        content: 'mw992';
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .myDiv:after {
        content: 'mw1200';
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myContainer">
    <div class="myDiv">                             
        myDiv inside myContainer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That way, you'd use less code to achieve basically the same thing.